# Automater Move Finder Items Error

Tags: finder, automator

I am trying to move any item ending with .package or .ts4script from Downloads into the folder called Mods. No matter what workflow I choose, I keep getting the error "The action 'Move Finder Items' was not supplied with the required data." What am I doing wrong? This is my current workflow:

Get Specified Finder Items
-chose the download folder

Get Folder Contents
-repeat for each subfolder found

Filter Finder Items
-any of the following are true:
-any content contains .package
-any content contains .ts4script

Move Finder Items
-to mods
-replace existing files

I am relatively new to automator so I would appreciate any help I can get! Thank you!

Comment: `Content` probably needs to be `file extension` (or `extension`) with the possible values of `"package"` or `"ts4script"` (no leading dot).  You could also test the `filename` (or `name`) to see if it ends with either of those two (with the leading dot retained).